# How do I make a parent div the height of its children?

Tags: html, css, menu

This seems like a really stupid question, but I can't figure it out.

I've got an UL styled into a horizontal menu, but the parent div won't adjust to the height of the child elements.  Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/STSjm/202/

HTML

```
<div class="menu">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.menu {
    background: blue;
}

.menu li{
    float: left;
    background: green;
}

.menu li a{
    background: red;
    padding: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
}

.menu li a:hover{
    background: orange;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: The clear method works well and .menu will be the height of his child. But the child of .menu is ul. And ul hasn't the height of his childs. So there is a problem between ul > li. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/STSjm/215/

Comment: jsfiddle version 202? You've been working pretty hard on this eh? ;)

Comment: Oh.  I'm new to jsFiddle too.  I definitely haven't done 205 iterations.

I remember now:  I took someone elses jsFiddle for a different question and just started working on it.  Maybe that's bad form...

If you go back to like 100, you'll see it was something completely different.

I'm just figuring all these newfangled tools out... forgive me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what's going on:

Your `<a>` elements have padding, but they are `display:inline` by default which adds padding *outside* the element, while not actually adding width/height to it, which is why the menu isn't expanding.

To fix this, set `display:block` to the anchors:

http://jsfiddle.net/STSjm/216/

In addition, you don't need the "clear" div, adding this CSS should do the trick:

```
.menu {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/STSjm/218/

There are also a number of CSS only "clearfix" tricks to solve this without adding extra unnecessary HTML markup.

Comment: No problem, welcome to the site and thanks for providing a clear, uncluttered explanation of your problem, with source code and a live demo. Excellent.